# Why does this OpenGL rotation also translate my object?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rotation, translate-animation

I'm trying to rotate an object (an arrow) which has it's default position as pointing to the right. I've been looking around and I'm using the glLoadIdentity() and glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() as a way to only rotate the object in my glBegin function and not the whole scene:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(5, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.01, yy2);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.06, yy2+0.03);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.06, yy2-0.03);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

However, it also translates my arrow, instead of only rotating it. Do I need to translate the offset back to it's original position? Or am I doing something wrong?

SOLVED:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(xx2, yy2, 0);
glRotatef(45, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-xx2, -yy2, 0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.01, yy2);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.06, yy2+0.03);
    glVertex2f(xx2-0.06, yy2-0.03);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Need to translate back to center (0, 0, 0), apply the rotation and then back to it's original position (xx2, yy2, 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All rotations are around the origin.

So yes, if you want to rotate around some other point, you must translate from that point to the origin, rotate, and then translate back again.

Comment: Isn't there a way to rotate around a given vertex of the arrow?

Comment: @safm Yes, there is. Move it so that the point is in origin, rotate, move it back.

Comment: You're right, I should have remembered that from my CG classes! 

Thank you!

Comment: "you must translate from that point to the origin" isn't it from the origin to that point? Basically moving the origin to that point's coordinates?

Comment: @marcospgp it's semantics.   If your rotation point is (3, 4, 5) you must translate the world by the _opposite_ of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you are applying your operations out of order. Specifically, you need to apply the rotation first, then apply the translation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you misunderstood it. I do not wish to translate the object. I want the arrow to rotate around it's vertex (the one pointing). Let's say it's always pointing to the right and I want to rotate 45 degrees so it points in a diagonal fashion.

Comment: @safm yes, per my answer, you do actually have to translate the object _deliberately_, twice.